# In C++, how to declare a class member that can only be changed externally?

Tags: c++

I have a class like this

```cpp
class Foo {
  public:
    Matrix M;

    Foo();
    ~Foo();
}
```

I want `M` to be immutable inside the class (internal member functions cannot change it), but code outside the class should be able to update it without constraint, is there a way to do so?

**A little background**:
I'm working on an OpenGL application, where I have a `Mesh` class that holds all the vertices/textures data and can `Draw()` on demand. I realized that the viewing matrix and projection matrix are global to the scene, while the model matrix `M` is local to every mesh, so I declared `M` as a public member of the `Mesh` class, which is initialized to the identity matrix. The caller outside the class should update `M` every frame to do transformations. However, I don't want it to be accidentally changed from within the class. Hope this makes sense.

This seems to be violating the `c++` principles, but I need to somehow tie `M` to an instance of the class. The `Matrix` type is actually `glm::mat4` btw.

Comment: Usually these types of constraints are useful because they can help prevent mistakes when using the class. A class can be used any number of times, so there are potentially many opportunities to make mistakes. You implement `Foo` once. You can easily prevent the mistake of modifying `M` internally with a simple code review of a single class. There doesn't seem to be all that much to gain from adding such a feature to the language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move `M` outside of `Foo`, and then give `Foo` a `const` pointer/reference to `M`, eg:

```cpp
Matrix M;

class Foo {
  public:
    const Matrix &Mref;

    Foo() : Mref(M) {}
    ~Foo();
};
```

Comment: Was just typing this up. This is exactly what OP wants.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what they want. The `Matrix` is owned by the `Foo`, it is an intrinsic property of the `class`.

Comment: From the question I understood something else because this was so obvious.

Comment: @neo-mashiro Of course, make sure `M` outlasts all instances of `Foo` or bad things will happen.

Answer (score 3):

How about something like

```
struct Matrix {
    void change() {}
};

class Foo {
  public:
    Matrix M;
    void bar() const {
        // M.change(); can't change since it's a const function.
    }
    Foo();
    ~Foo();
};

int main() {
    Foo f;
    f.M.change();
}
```

Have all operations inside `Foo` within `const` functions, yet expose `M` itself to the outer world.

Comment: The downside to this approach is if `Foo` has other methods that are not `const`-qualified because they need to access/mutate *other* non-const data, but they *also* want to access `M` as well. Then they have non-const access to mutate `M`, even if accidentally.  Exactly what the OP wants to avoid.